# java.net.UnknownHostException: <<hostname>> : unknown error

Tags: java, oracle, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to establish Oracle DB connection from the application which runs on an EC2 instance of AWS. Oracle DB is in on-prem server. Firewall has been opened and I'm able to telnet to the SCAN and VIP hosts of that DB from my EC2 instance. But, still I'm getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:392) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:434) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:687) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:343) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
... 239 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: <<hostname>>: unknown error
at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105) ~[na:1.8.0_40-internal]
at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:117) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:370) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
```

JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
(HOST = <<IP address of the host>>)(PORT = 1590)))(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = <<example.service.com>>)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)
(METHOD = BASIC))))`
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using java 8 ? If so then probably it's related to [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8135259)

Java 7 or 9 would probably give you a more useful error message instead of "unknown error" (eg possibly "Name or service not known")

Apart from that, did you try a tnsping from the host you're trying to connect from ?

Also as per the below in the [Oracle driver documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)  when using a tnsnames entry in the jdbc URL it should be as below, using OCI driver :

*Note that you can also specify the database by a TNSNAMES entry. You can find the available TNSNAMES entries listed in the file tnsnames.ora on the client computer from which you are connecting. For example, if you want to connect to the database on host myhost as user scott with password tiger that has a TNSNAMES entry of MyHostString, enter:*

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:oracle:oci8:@MyHostString","scott","tiger");
```